# Can I tie a knot in a strict data type?

Tags: haskell

The streaming package defines

```
data Stream f m r = Step !(f (Stream f m r))
                  | Effect (m (Stream f m r))
                  | Return r
```

Its implementation of `empty`, called `never`, is defined

```
never :: (Monad m, Applicative f)
      => Stream f m r
never = let loop = Effect (return (Step (pure loop))) in loop
```

That's all very monadic for something essentially pure, something the library generally tries to avoid for performance reasons. The obvious pure version would be

```
never = let loop = Step (pure loop) in loop
```

Unfortunately, since `Step` is strict, this will blow up for a functor with a strict `pure`, such as `Identity`. Is there any way around this? My only idea is absurdly unsafe, and I don't know if it can go horribly wrong.

```
data StreamL f m r = StepL (f (StreamL f m r))
                   | EffectL (m (StreamL f m r))
                   | ReturnL r

never :: forall f m r. Applicative f => Stream f m r
never = case loop of
          StepL x -> x `pseq` unsafeCoerce loop
   where
     loop :: StreamL f m r
     loop = StepL (pure loop)
     {-# NOINLINE loop #-}
{-# NOINLINE never #-}
```

The idea is to build something just like `never`, but with a lazy `StepL` constructor. Then make sure everything is actually forced and magic it into the stricter type.

Comment: Why do you care how fast something never happens?

Comment: As far as I know, strict and non-strict types have different in-memory representations, so the `unsafeCoerce` hack will basically never work.

Comment: @Cirdec, `never` never *returns*, but that's okay. For `Stream (a,) m r`, `never` is an infinite stream of `mempty` values. Is it *important*? That I couldn't say.

Comment: @user2407038, I'll have to experiment, but that doesn't sound right (except when there's unboxing, which there isn't here). Each non-unboxed field containing a value of a lifted type is a pointer to a closure representing a value of that type. The runtime keeps track of whether it's evaluated or not, but I don't *think* it knows if it's a strict field.

Comment: I just realized one possible safe compromise would be to use a longer loop: `never = fix $ Step . pure . Step . pure . ... . Effect . return`. This follows more pointers than I'd like and I don't know what a CPU will think of it.

Comment: It looks like I was wrong (at least, I can't find an example for which I was right). I thought that evaluating `never` would use the semantics of `Stream` and not `StreamL`, but in hindsight this couldn't possibly make sense - the runtime knows nothing of types, so the `unsafeCoerce`d value can't magically change its evaluation semantics. (I suppose things could still break if some other library code assumes that it takes input which is strict in `Step`, but I don't see how one could make use of such an assumption)

Comment: @user2407038, I think `pure` would have to reach into the `StepL`. The only ways I can think of doing that are with `unsafeCoerce` and with the magical version of `deepseq` used for compact regions. It's hard to imagine why `pure` would ever do either of these to its argument.

Comment: What I would worry about with `Never` is not the small overhead of monadic actions (which are often even optimized away) but of an asymptotic bad case like `msum [never, never, never, never, something, never, never, never, never]` (etc) which does a lot of work maintaining the nevers because it can't see into the future.  To solve this you could adapt `Stream` (wrap it up in a transfomer of sorts) to explicitly represent `Never` so that you can collapse them away when they are combined.  I wouldn't try this without an actual performance problem case and a profiler, though.

Comment: @luqui, I acknowledge that this may not be the most practically important efficiency concern, but it's kind of sad. With my generality hat on, I imagine inefficient monads, like strict-spined lists without rewrite rules.